# PHP extract number only from result explode

Tags: php, regex, explode

I have explode here is the result of `var_dump`:

[image: result of explode]

and I want get the result from explode:

```
7 [remove other string]
0 [if contain "-"]
0 [if contain "-"]
0 [if contain "-"]
```

Here, I just used `comma` as delimiter:

```
var_dump (explode(",", $rowData[0][13]));
die();
```

Does anyone have the solution to solved this?

Thank You.

Comment: Hey, instead of adding an image, paste the result of the explode in here.

Comment: @iagowp here it is : array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "JZ8"
  [1]=>
  string(3) " B-"
  [2]=>
  string(3) " S-"
  [3]=>
  string(3) " M-"
}

Comment: Also, you should post what have you tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_map()` function and in it use `filter_var()` to sanitize number value.

Try

```
$rowData = ['JJ7', 'B-', 'S-', 'M-'];

$result = array_map(function($v) { 
    return abs((int) filter_var($v, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)); 
}, $rowData );

var_dump( $result );

//output
// array(4) { [0]=> int(7) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data_result = explode(",", $rowData[0][13])

for($data_count=0;$data_count<count($data_result);$data_count++)
{
    if(substr($data_result[$data_count], -1) == '-')    
    {
        echo $data_result[$data_count]
    }
}
?>
```